# Normalizing OFDM after IFFT

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, digital-communications, ofdm

I had a question about normalizing OFDM transmit power after IFFT across each subcarrier. I have simulated OFDM with BPSK and according to different website I have used `NFFT/sqrt(Nsubcarrier_used)*ifft(x)` where `x` is the modulated signal and `NFFT` is the size of `ifft` and `Nsubcarrier_used` is total number of subcarrier that is used. This gives me the transmit power of $1$ across each subcarrier.

My question is: How to know the scaling factor, such as `NFFT/sqrt(Nsubcarrier_used)`, of different modulation schemes?

Because I have tried the same scaling factor for 16-QAM [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25694-ber-of-ofdm-using-16-qam-in-awgn?focused=5140092&tab=function) and it did not give me $1$ as a transmit power. Therefore I would really appreciate if anyone can explain about the method to find the scaling factor for FFT and IFFT in OFDM.

Comment: The FFT scaling factors have been covered in numerous posts on here. The truth is that real transmit signals don't normalize for the FFT length, they just use the numbers as they come out of the FFT. The absolute amplitudes simply don't matter, since a digital number doesn't have any physical unit.

Comment: Thanks. I looked at many posts but they did not explain about this scaling factor used in IFFT or FFT in OFDM. can you please guide to posts here or quickly mention what would be the scaling for different modulation ?

Comment: simple: it wouldn't apply. Scaling is just done to ensure some mathematical properties of the transform. For transmission, the absolute amplitude doesn't matter, and scaling, if at all, is done to achieve other things, totally unrelated to the length of the FFT.

Comment: BUT IT WILL AFFECT THE BER. If the Transmit power is not 1 the BER would not be acceptable like the link I referred to if the scaling is not correct the theoretical and simulated curve do not match.

Comment: That's a totally different problem. It only applies to simulation/theory. And, in theory, you're doing the math yourself, so you obviously in charge of setting the average power to 1 yourself, and have to figure out, based on your own formulas, what the right normalization factor is! You've got all the math you need (i.e. mathematical definition of the FFT you're using, power of the symbols, Parseval's theorem), so you're the only one who can calculate what the right normalization factor would be!